# how to distinguish between “EditText” inputed manually and inputed by "setText()"

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a trouble that how to judge `EditText` inputed manually and inputed by `setText()`?
I have tried to use `addTextChangedListener`:

```
TextWatcher textWeatherListener = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Log.i("TAG","inputed");
    }
};
```

and print `Log` in `afterTextChanged(Editable s)`,but no matter what way I input manually or input by `setText()`, the `Log` is printed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a soluation:

```
private boolean isTextSetProgrammatically = false;

private void setTextProgrammatically(String text) {
    mEditTextWeather.removeTextChangedListener(textWeatherListener);
    mEditTextWeather.setText(text);
    isTextSetProgrammatically = true;
    mEditTextWeather.addTextChangedListener(textWeatherListener);
}
```

then  set a `TextWatcher` to  `EditText` and set `isTextSetProgrammatically` to false when `onTextChanged()` gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend class EditText in your custom class and override method SetText, where you can make a log

Comment: when i input manually ,if excute setText()?

Comment: No you cant! setText is a final method and cannot be changed in a Custom Edittext

Comment: Ahh, i'm very sorry, i didn't know, it's my mistake

Comment: no problem, thank you！

Answer (score 0):

You are the one calling the setText() method. You can just set a flag when you do that.

Comment: when i input manually ,if excute setText()?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the comment.

Comment: when i input manually ,if excute setText() in the Class EditText inside?